# What's the right way of making an absolute positioned Component that has children in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, layout, react-native

I'd like to create an app that looks similar to Google Maps in a way it also has a search bar at the top.
I'm new to React Native, not sure how to achieve this. If I only use a TextInput with `position:absolute, top: 5`  etc., it works, the component is placed onto the Map.
If I wrap that into a custom component called `SearchBar` then it goes to the bottom of the screen under / next to the Map. I need to wrap it because the goal is to have a `SearchBar` custom component the has a `TextInput` and a `Button`.

SearchBar:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles2.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles2.input}
          placeholder="Enter your start point"
          onChangeText={text => console.log({text})}
        />
        <Button style={styles2.button} title="+" onPress={() => undefined} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles2 = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  input: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  button: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 25,
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
})
```

Main view:

```
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Map style={styles.map} />
        <SearchBar/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  searchBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    height: 50,
    zIndex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a style prop to you custom component `<SearchBar style={styles.searchBar}/>` and then in the component definition retrieve the passed style prop and assign it to the container View like this :

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles2.container,this.props.style]}>
          .
          .
          .
      </View>
     );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I deal with positioning components on top of a full screen flex-box component is to make the outermost wrapper positioned absolutely to the edges of the window, make another wrapper for the fullscreen flex-box which is also positioned absolutely to the edges of the window, and then add the component that will be positioned on top to the outermost wrapper.

In your `Main` component that looks like this:

```
class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.edges}>
        <View style={styles.edges}>
          <Map style={styles.map} />
        </View>
        <SearchBar/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  edges: {
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
    position: absolute,
    right: 0,
    top: 0
  }
  searchBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    height: 50,
    zIndex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
  },
})
```

Hope that helps!

Note: You may need to change some of your SearchBar and Map styles to get this working properly.